# problem with regxp

Tags: php, regex

My php script should validiate address of websites, that user type into the form.
Adress should look like this:

`http://example.com/example/{some numbers}/`

or

`http://example.com/example/{some numbers}`

And I have think about something like this, but it doesn't work:

`/^(http:\/\/)?example\.com\/example\/\d{1}(\/?)$/`

Can you show me where I'm wrong?

Comment: What platform are you using? There are handy little regexp testers available for almost all platforms, e.g. for mac os there is reggie, and I'm sure theres one for windows too. Having such a thing makes it a whole lot easier to debug this stuff!

Comment: A side note: when using a different delimiter, there's no need to escape those slashes: `#^(http://)?example\.com/example/\d+(/?)$#`. Much better, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\d{1}` means: ONLY one digit. Maybe you want to do `\d+` (at least one digit)

Answer (score 0):

hm, some numbers or some number? In case you meant the first case, the greedy modifier is wrong, because it tells your regexp to only match exactly one decimal. Besides, it works just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP's built-in [filter mechanism](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for this?

```
filter_var('http://example.com/foo', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); // returns the URL
filter_var('not an URL', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);           // returns false
```

Explore [some examples](http://www.talkincode.com/php-filter-filter_validate_url-limitations-124.html).

In addition, there is [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) which lets you split any URL into it's components.